# Aptana Studio 3 No local history available for selected resource

Tags: osx-elcapitan, aptana3

This problem is happening under OSX 10.11.2 with Aptana Studio 3.6.1 "AS3"

I created a folder on my hard drive named it projectFolder, and some subfolders with some html/css/js files. Then using a different editor, I did some coding. Then started AS3, right click on projectFolder and did Promote to Project, accepted the default with Project Type = Web, then edited my.html file and saved it.

In the Project Explorer on my.html, RightClick > Compare With > Local History...
but a pop up window saying "No local history available for selected resource".

Please help me find what I am doing wrong in order to get this functionality to work.

Thanks

Comment: this has nothing to do with AS3, please remove that tag.

Comment: Fixed, I left the machine overnight, next morning it was working. no clue as to why.